# /me/home in graph api stopped working

Tags: facebook-graph-api

The /me/home request in the graph api stopped working. 
All other requests in the graph api like /me/feed still work. 
Can someone verify/check this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working for me. Try it on the [graph explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me/home).  Make sure you still have read_stream permissions by checking /me/permissions.

Comment: I can confirm it works again but it definitely did not for a few hours back then.